# Reload page but get a 404 error because of wrong url when routing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing

My View is called `Survey.cshtml`. My current url is `http://localhost:17471/Campaign/Survey/6184`.

In this page I have a drop down menu to select language. There are English and Spanish. One I select the language, I want to reload the page because some context are shown in different language. I still want to keep the same url.

My code in `Survey.cshtml`.

```
 $("#id").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Survey1", "Campaign", new {id=Model.SurveyModel.CampaignId, languageName = "languageToken" })".replace("languageToken", selectedValue);

        });
```

However it goes to the url `http://localhost:17471/Campaign/Survey1/6184?languageName=Spanish`

My controller `CampaignController.cs` has the methods.

```
    public ActionResult Survey(int id)
    {
       // omitted code
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Survey1(int id, string languageName)
    {
        // omitted here
        var view = "Survey";
        return View(view,model);
    }
```

I don't have Route for the above methods in RouteConfig.cs. I am not very strong on MVC Routing. Sometimes I am confused the old-and-good HTTP URL ENCODING with the `http://site-address/page.html?param1=value1&param2=value2` and the MVC ROUTING which uses the form of `http://site-address/page/value1/value2`.

So help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Survey1` action is decorated with `[HttpPost]`, which means you have to use the POST method from your client. But when you do a redirect with `window.location.href`, that always uses the GET method. You have two options:

1. Change your controller action and remove `[HttpPost]`.
2. Create a form with the POST method and your values in it, and use javascript to trigger the `submit` event on that form instead of using `window.location.href`.

Comment: It works out after I removed `[HttpPost]`. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear.